# Implement counter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I will be printing two fields using for fields using for loop in javascript. First field is the name and second field is the link to download that file. This table will be generated dynamically. I want to keep a counter saying how many times a particular file is downloaded on the generated table.

```
 for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
            var titulo = resp.items[i].title;
            var fechaUpd = resp.items[i].modifiedDate;
            var userUpd = resp.items[i].lastModifyingUserName;
            var userEmbed = resp.items[i].embedLink;
            var userAltLink = resp.items[i].alternateLink;
            var download = resp.items[i].webContentLink;
            var hold="Download";
            var flag=0;

           <!-- var fileInfo = document.createElement('li');
          <!--  fileInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode('TITLE: ' + titulo + ' - LAST MODIF: ' + fechaUpd + ' - BY: ' + userUpd +'  url:  ' + hold.link(download)));                
           <!-- document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fileInfo);

            document.write(titulo + "&nbsp;");
            document.write(hold.link(download) + "<br>");
            <!--flag=1;
            }

            <!--if(flag!=1){
            <!--document.write("not found!");
            <!--}
    });
```

Comment: why don't you print out the i value as it is incrementing automatically inside the loop where ever you want to?

Comment: See this is retrieving values from google drive even if i use the index value whats the use? Because once its printed out it cant access it again right. and how would i know whether i am clicking download for a particular file?

Comment: sorry, i thought you just want to print out the counter. Now after reading again, i understood that what you want to do is keep a counter of the number of times the file has been downloaded or the link is clicked. well, in this case you will have to store the number of clicks of a particular file. Do you get unique file id(s) from google drive? i don't know, that's why asking?

Comment: Right now am not retrieving any unique id from google. I know its possible to get the file id. But can i create the counter with whatever i have?